# What options are there for inexpensive 35mm film developing and digitizing?

Tags: film, 35mm, developing, digitizing

I have a large number of rolls of undeveloped 35mm file (over 100). What are some places I can find that will develop these for a reasonable price, and ideally digitize them for online download at the same time? So far the cheapest I have found is York Photo, who will develop the film + 1 set of prints for $4.50 (includes S&H) + $1 to digitize the photos. But I have no idea of their quality.

Comment: What region are you in?

Comment: In the USA (California specifically)

Comment: This question about [getting film developed by mail](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4434/where-is-a-really-good-place-to-get-film-developed-by-mail) might also help.

Answer (score 6):

Currently (July 2010) in the UK:

- [photo express](http://www.photo-express.co.uk/digital.html) develop & scan 35mm or APS to 2048 x 3072 on CD for £4.50
- [Metro Colour Lab](http://www.metrocolourlab.com/index_files/Metrocolourlab_C41.htm) develop & scan 35mm to 4MB on CD for £6.50 or £7 for 18MB
- [peak imaging](http://www.peak-imaging.com/htmls/process_and_scan_to_cd.htm) develop & scan 35mm to 1800 x 1200 on CD for £6.96 (or more for higher resolution)

Answer (score 5):

Certain [Costco](http://shop.costco.com/Photo-Center/Index) locations do develop & scan (3000x2000) to CD for ~$5. You'll have to call to see if one near you provides it.

Comment: Of my tests, not only was Costco cheap, but it also consistently produced the best-looking scans.  Walmart was a shade cheaper, but the quality was *terrible*.

Comment: Some quality samples: http://www.flickr.com/photos/ninja999/1749937078/lightbox/  http://www.flickr.com/photos/ninja999/1509294615/lightbox/

Comment: Update - Costco has stopped providing film service

Answer (score 2):

- [CVS/Eckerds](http://www.cvsphoto.com/)
- [Target](http://sites.target.com/site/en/spot/page.jsp?title=photo_center)
- [Walgreens](http://photo.walgreens.com/)

All very cheap, although I prefer Target.

Answer (score 0):

Go to CVS! Very easy and the price is right. They always have deals on developing.

Answer (score 0):

I've used these guys and was very pleased with the service:
http://www.northcoastphoto.com/index.html

(They are also recommended here by [ken rockwell](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/labs.htm))

Comment: The bracketed comment is not necessarily a positive.