# Where is a really good place to get film developed by mail?

Tags: film, scanning, developing, scanning-service

I'm looking for a place to get my 35mm film (color slide and B&W) developed and scanned by mail with a focus on *quality*.  I have a good local shop about 10mi away from me that does great development but horrible *horrible* scanning and its a PITA to drive up there.

I noticed another person asked about [online photo developing with an eye on inexpensiveness](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/inexpensive-35mm-film-developing), but I'm looking for quality developing/scanning, something on par to if I did it myself with my Nikon 5000ED scanner (which I'd like to sell as I don't want to do it myself anymore).

Comment: Are we talking about somewhere within the US here?

Comment: Yup, w/in the US.  On the west coast for bonus points.

Comment: Would this question be community wiki material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for film developers, too.

I stumbled upon Ken Rockwell's recommendation of North Coast Photo http://www.northcoastphoto.com/

I haven't used them myself.. so can't speak.

Comment: Ultimately went with North Coast Photo as they offer a really good price for their high quality scans (> 16MP).  I tried http://thedarkroom.com/ as well, they're ok but their larger scan sizes were too small for the amount they were charging in comparison to NCP.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [A&I](http://www.aandi.com/) a few times. They have a good reputation and I was happy, though I'm not a film expert by any means. I think you have to pay extra for good scans (the ones I got were fine but nothing special).

Comment: Thanks reid, I sent them an email asking for some more information.  I'll send some recent film off and see what I get back :)

Comment: @Shizam How did this go?